# Covariance Matrix of various x,y,z(cartesian coordinates)

Tags: matrix, covariance

I have around 1000 values of gps receiver positions as follows:
I have to calculate the covariance matrix with all these values. How can I get a covariance matrix?

[image: the first 15 values]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The covariance of random variables (X, Y) is defined by

```
Cov(X,Y) = E(X-EX)(Y-EY)'
```

where ' is transpose. For this sample matrix, call it P, you need to compute

```
COV = (P - EP)' (P - EP) / (N-1)
```

which is the inner product. Your P is (N x 3), so COV will be (3 x 3). The expectation EP is the sample mean for each column, so EP is also an (N x 3) matrix.